# Better way to build JSON array and retrieve its elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here's how I'm initializing and building an array:

```
var newCountyInfo = new Object();

newCountyInfo.name = newCountyName;
newCountyInfo.state = newCountyState;
newCountyInfo.zips = newCountyZips;
newCountyInfo.branchID = newCountyBranchID;
```

So I have my four elements in the array. I'm then passing newCountyInfo to another function to pull out the elements for display in some HTML elements.

The only way **I** know how to get to the individual elements in the function that uses them is this:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newCountyValidation)).name
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newCountyValidation)).state
... etc...
```

There's got to be a better/shorter/more elegant way of doing this!

What is it?

Comment: That's not a "JSON array", that's a normal JavaScript object. You really should read about what JSON is (a data exchange format) and what `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` are doing. Then you would notice that calling them like this is just unnecessary.

Comment: you would only need to use json if you were passing your object to say PHP or using it to create a cross domain api (jsonP). since you're not doing either of those, using a regular object literal `{}` would be the way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you serializing *at all?* I don't understand what JSON has to do with this, unless you're using [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers), [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX), or something else which demands serialization. Start with [object literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals):

```
var newCountyInfo = {
    name: newCountyName,
    state: newCountyState,
    zips: newCountyZips,
    branchID: newCountyBranchID
};
```

And just pass the whole object to the other function:

```
someOtherFunction(newCountyInfo);
```

Which can access the fields using [plain old property accesses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators):

```
function someOtherFunction(foo) {
    console.log(foo.name); // whatever was in newCountyname
}
```

No JSON whatsoever.

Comment: I have to know, why were you shoveling the object through JSON like that? What made you think that was the right approach?

Comment: As it is apparently quite clear, I haven't messed with arrays too much, with the exception of getting an array of data from a PHP/MySQL return to an $.ajax call. In which case I use a JSON array. I assumed that this was just one way to handle arrays in Javascript in general. Now I know differently...

Comment: @Mathletics I am guessing the OP is (ab)using the term as PHP does, blurring the line between an object and an array.

Comment: @eventide unlike in PHP, a JS array is distinctly different from a JS object. I suggest you get a handle on that ASAP. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work just fine:

```
var newCountyInfo = {
    name: newCountyName,
    state: newCountyState,
    zips: newCountyZips,
    branchID: newCountyBranchID
}

function test(newCountyValidation)
{
    alert(newCountyValidation.name);
}

test(newCountyInfo);
```